# Adding keys to elements other than li in React

Tags: reactjs

This is a pretty straight forward question, I'm an absolute beginner and I couldn't find an answer in the docs, so I'm coming here for help.

If React needs keys for each list item in order to identify it and change if needed , why is it only limited to li?

Say I have a structure like this:

```
        <div>
            <div>Div 1</div>
            <div>Div 2</div>
            <div>Div 3</div>
            <div>Div 4</div>
        </div>
```

Shouldn't react have keys for each of the div elements so it can identify and render changes faster?

Comment: It's not just limited to `li` elements. You should give a `key` prop to every element in an array you render. It doesn't matter if you write `<div>{[1,2].map(e => <div key={e}>{e}</div>)}<div>` or `<ul>{[1,2].map(e => <li key={e}>{e}</li>)}<ul>`

Comment: The keys are not limited to li tag. It is applied to any html tags or React components which are generated dynamically; say using objects or lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of keys in React is not limited to `li` elements but to any JSX element that is being rendered in dynamically in an iterator. For static JSX content, you do not need keys.

For example, when you render the elements like

```
 <div>
        <div>Div 1</div>
        <div>Div 2</div>
        <div>Div 3</div>
        <div>Div 4</div>
 </div>
```

you need to specify keys to the divs because while creating the Virtual DOM react knows which elements are defined where and which elements to compare during an update. The static content, even if is rendered using a conditional render will follow the same order always and has a guarantee that if you follow the correct patterns it won't be randomly deleted from the dom or reordered within the dom and hence React can rely on the Virtual DOM generated the first time to compare elements.

However when you are rendering the elements using an iterator, its possible that you change the order of your data, add some data or possibly even delete some of the data, which would lead to a change in the number of JSX elements rendered or the order in which they were rendered. In such a case, react needs to know which elements to compare during consecutive renders. Hence you need a key

An example of such a case would be

```
state = {
   data: [1,2,3,4]
}
<div>
     {this.state.map(value => {
          return <div key={value}>Div {value}</div>
     })}
 </div>
```

In the above case, you may decide to sort the data in decreasing order and hence the elements will be rendered like

```
    <div>Div 4</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 1</div>
```

and if the returned elements were provided a key react would know which elements to compare and hence not cause a complete render.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why static JSX does not need keys? 
That was the purpose of my question, thanks.

Comment: @ZafirStojanovski I updated my answer to add more explanation to it